# how to connect multiple tables with Laravel models

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 7.
I want to retrieve all the users that are active and belong to Austria.
I would like to do that using laravel relationships.
There are three tables that should be connected through the models: `countries`, `users` and `user_details`.

Country.php:

```
public function user_details()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\UserDetail', 'citizenship_country_id', 'id');
}
```

User_detail.php:

```
public function country()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Country', 'citizenship_country_id', 'id');
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

User.php:

```
public function user_detail()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\UserDetail', 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

In the controller I used the following code to retrieve all austrian users that are active:

```
return Country::where('name', 'Austria')->first()->user_details()->first()->user()->where('active', '1')->get();
```

I should visualize two users but I get only one user. I suppose the error is the second `first`.

Can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This.

```php
$users = User::whereHas('user_details.country', function ($query) { 
    $query->where('countries.name', "Austria"); 
})
->where("active",1)
->get();
```